# Can't share URL on twitter with a query string

Tags: html, twitter, hyperlink

I'm trying to tweet a URL with a query string and it's not working correctly. The URL is formed like this: `http://example.com/videos/watch?v=123`

My code is below

```
<a class="tw" href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?status=<?= urlencode($video[0]['tweet_text']) . 'http://example.com/videos/watch?v=' $video[0]['_pw']['id'] ?>">Tweet</a>
```

When I remove the number after `v=`, the tweet dialog shows up. When I keep the `?v=123`, the tweet dialog just loads twitter.com.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to encode the text and the url

```php
<a class="tw" href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?status=<?= urlencode($video[0]['tweet_text'] . 'http://domain.com/videos/watch?v=' $video[0]['_pw']['id']) ?>">Tweet</a>
```